# Inner join three tables to java DTO

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing the following problem...
[image]

I'm trying to have a java list of `ProcessDTO` object of both `process` and `subprocess` in this way:

```
[{"process": {
   "code": "AB",
   "name": "Proc1"
   "subprocesses": 
    [{"code": "cd", "name": "subProc1"}],
    [{"code": "ef", "name": "subProc2"}],
    [{"code": "gh", "name": "subProc3"}]
  }
}]
```

This is what I have till now:

```
SELECT distinct C.code as process_code, C.name as process_name, A.code as subprocess_code, A.name as subprocess_code FROM subprocess A 
inner join zone B
    on A.id = B.subprocess_id
inner join process C
    on C.id = B.process_id
    ORDER BY C.code;
```

But when I create the DTO class:

```
public class ProcessDto {

    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private List<Subprocess> subprocess;

}
```

And the query:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(itemResourceRel = "process", collectionResourceRel = "processes", path = "process")
public interface ProcessDataRestRepository extends JpaRepository<Process, Long> {

    @Query("Select p.code, p.name, sp.code, sp.name " +
            "from Process p " +
            "inner join Zone z on p.id = z.process " +
            "inner join Subprocess sp on sp.id = z.subprocess")
    List<ProcessDto> findProcessesAndSubprocesses();

}
```

I get the following error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
>   to type [dto.ProcessSubprocess]

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

A dirty way would be to do a findAll of the processes, store in an object, then iterate them and find all the subprocesses...

Is there any other way to bring everything from de BBDD and have it in an object?

Answer (score 3):

Make an interface from that DTO so Spring engine can pick it up and create a result object automatically:

```
public interface ProcessDto {

    Long getId();
    String getCode();
    String getName();
    String getSubprocessName();

}
```

More on the subject [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Comment: I just did thid this and it makes sense, I'm getting closer. Problem is I need the subprocesses as a list and actually I get an object like this: `{name: "Proc1", id: 1, code: "AB", subprocessName: "subProc1", subprocessCode: "cd"}`. Is there any way to have `List<Subprocess> getSubprocesses()` in the interface?

Comment: You should be able to. Just create one more itnerface for Subprocess and use it in the ProcessDto interface as a getter. Try just running findAll() at first.

Comment: I tried and it works well for @ManyToOne but the lists do not seem to get picked up. You might need a custom parser or run a query for each of the Processes to get the Subprocesses. But the second option might slow things down.